# How to get menu text vertically aligned with inherited height

Tags: css

I have a pretty standard Bootstrap nav menu with some custom modifications. An issue I'm having with the nav is with both the a:hover selector and vertical-align property. I need to have the a:hover selector fill 100% of the height of the menu bar, but as soon I get this working, my vertical align effect stops working (and vice versa). How can I meet both requirements?

(For clarity, see my comment in the CSS code)

Thanks.

Here is my Fiddle -- Code also below...

http://jsfiddle.net/n2fole00/42d30eoh/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#secondary-menu-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div id="secondary-menu-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">ONE</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">TWO TWO</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">THREE THREE THREE</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">FIVE FIVE FIVE FIVE FIVE</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
#secondary-menu-collapse .navbar-nav {
    display: table; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#secondary-menu-collapse .navbar-nav li {
    width: 20%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
    float:none;
    height:inherit;
}

#secondary-menu-collapse .navbar-nav li a {
    height:inherit; /* Removing this gives the correct vertical alignment, but the background hover doesn't fill the height of the menu bar. */
}

#secondary-menu-collapse .navbar-nav li a:hover {
    background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it **have** to be the `a` selector?

If you just have the `:hover` on the `li` item, like so:

```
#secondary-menu-collapse .navbar-nav li:hover {
    background-color:green;
}
```

then the whole list item (rather than just the text inside, which is in the anchor tag) will have its background color become green. Then you can remove the `height:inherit;` property from the anchor tag.

This will make the background green for ALL hovered items. If you want the active item to stay black, you can also add:

```
#secondary-menu-collapse .navbar-nav .active {
    background-color: #080808 !important; /* The !important makes sure this has priority */
}
```

[**Updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/42d30eoh/5/)

Alternatively, if you don't want to use `!important` or you want a different color when you hover on the active item, you can use this instead:

```
#secondary-menu-collapse .navbar-nav .active:hover {
    background-color: #BBBBBB; /* Set a hover color for the active item here */
}
```

Comment: there is a problem when you hover on the active link

Comment: Well you didn't specify if you wanted the hover effect on the active item too. See edited answer for how to keep it the same color.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. The hover effect would have to indicate the area was clickable. It's a great idea though ;)

Comment: The next step could be to use jQuery to make that li clickable, but then I wanted to know if this was possible with vanilla CSS.

Comment: Not likely, the way you have it set up with table cells. But you can [check this question out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696028/how-do-i-use-jquery-to-select-a-whole-li-tag-and-make-it-a-link) for a jQuery way to do it.

Comment: Ok, thanks Calvin. I did it like this and used some jQuery like you linked to. Looks good :) Thanks.